# Parity and number of draws in a hockey tournament

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math

> A one-round hockey tournament is finished (each plays with each one time, the winner gets $2$ points, loser gets $0$, and $1$ point for draw). For any arbitrary subgroup of teams there exists a team (that may be from that subgroup) that has got an odd number of points in the games with the teams of the subgroup. Prove that there was even number of teams. *(Source: All Soviet Union 1972)*

My solution is this:

> Let $n$ denote the number of participants in the tournament. Let $a_i$ denote the number of draws done by the $i^\text{th}$ team. For every subgroup of teams, there exists a team that has drawn with the teams of the subgroup an odd number of times (call this team a good team for a subgroup of size $k$). For the sake of finding a contradiction, assume that if there are an odd number of participants the condition is still possible.
>
> We know that$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$$is an even number (no matter the parity of $n$), since it counts each team involved in each draw once. When we choose a subgroup of size $k$, we would like a team either from the $n-k$ other participants who has drawn with an odd number of teams in the subgroup, or a team from the subgroup that has drawn with an odd number of teams in the subgroup.
>
> Clearly for a subgroup of size $1$, finding a good team in the subgroup is impossible, so we must look to the $n-1$ participants. If any one of the $n-1$ participants have drawn with the one in the subgroup, then that participant is a good team. Since taking any subgroup of teams will enable us to find a good team, each of the participants must have drawn at least once.
>
> For a subgroup of size $n$, we must find a good team in the subgroup. So at least one of the $n$ teams must have drawn an odd number of times. For $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ to remain an even number, there must be a positive even number of teams that have drawn an odd number of times. We are looking at odd quantities of $n$, so at least one team has drawn an even number of times.
>
> For a subgroup of size $n-1$, either the one participant left out of the subgroup must be a good team, or a participant inside the subgroup must have drawn an odd number of times with the teams in the subgroup. If the participant left out has drawn an odd number of times, then that team is good in this case. If the participant left out (call this participant $L$) has drawn an even number of times, either there is a subgroup team that has drawn an odd number of times and did not draw with $L$, or a subgroup team that has drawn an even number of times and has drawn with $L$.
>
> But then $L$ could draw with all of the teams that have an odd number of draws, and since there are an even number of them, it is possible for $L$ to have no more draws with any other team. Then since any other team that has drawn an even number of times still has drawn an even number of times with the other teams in the subgroup, there is no good team we can find here. This is a contradiction, so we conclude that $n$ cannot be odd, and must therefore be even.

I'm not sure the reasoning used here is entirely correct. There is no solution provided on the site I got this from. Also, I'm not sure that knowing the fact that each team has at least one draw is even necessary. Can anyone check over my solution?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're doing in the last 2 paragraphs. I'm guessing the fact that no one else has commented in the past 2 days suggests that it's hard to follow what you're saying (which isn't unusual for combinatorics proofs). I suggest that you write that up better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: I don't understand what you were doing in the last 2 paragraphs.)

As far as I can tell, you only consider subgroups of size

- 1  -> Conclude that every team must have drawn at least once
- $n$ -> Conclude that an (even number of) team drew an odd number of times.
- $n-1$ -> Did something here that I didn't quite understand.

**If you considered no other subgroups**, then I am confident that your proof is insufficient / incorrect, because I can find a counter example with $n = 5$, where the subgroups of size $1, 5, 4$ all have an odd-count.

I encourage you to find such an example, and then review your reasoning in the last 2 paragraphs to see where the error was made.

> Take the edges (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2, 3)
>  12345 -> 4 and 5 have an odd-count
>  2345 -> 2 and 3  have an odd-count
>  all other subgroups not involving 1 -> 1 has an odd count (possibly others).