Malaysian IMONST2 2022 Problem 6 (Under specific conditions, prove that a given tournament has an even number of teams)
This is the 6th problem from the Malaysian IMONST2 for year 2022.
"A football league has $n$ teams. Each team plays one game with every other team. Each win is awarded 2 points, each tie 1 point, and each loss 0 point.
After the league is over, the following statement is true: for every subset $S$ of teams in
the league, there is a team (which may or may not be in $S$) such that the total points
the team obtained by playing all the teams in $S$ is odd.
Prove that $n$ is even."
I've already tried this problem for a few hours already, and I have not been able to think of a solution. My only observation, which I still don't know if it will be important: regardless of the outcome of the matches, the total points obtained by both teams in any matchup will always be 2 points, so the total points of all teams after all games will always be even.
I think the solution requires two things:

Prove that even $n$ could work
Disprove for odd $n$

which I cannot do either currently.

Should $S$ be a proper subset? If $S$ is the set of all teams, then clearly this doesn’t make sense.

I honestly don't know, the phrasing was copied word for word, and what saw you is exactly the problem given.
https://imo-malaysia.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/imonst-2-2022-3-senior-1.pdf
Here's the link to the actual document containing the problem.

What I understood is this: S is just a naming for a possible subsets of the teams. (Meaning it could have any 1 team, any 2 teams, up to all teams), and honestly, even if the team is in set S, can't you just argue that it can't play with itself, so it gets 0 points?

I just realized that this question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4104823/715329

@Pranay Not quite. That is a solution verification problem, for which I posted an answer indicating that their solution is incorrect. We're still missing an actual solution.

@CalvinLin you are right, I should have said it’s a related question. I see that there’s no solution there yet. My solution is clearly not the intended solution, but I don’t yet have any ideas for the intended question.

Preamble:

I do not like this answer because it uses linear algebra to finish the argument, which I do not expect from the Malaysia TST.
In fact, the pure linear algebra solution is very short (See my last note).
Given the similarity to Even/Oddtown, it's not too surprising that linear algebra is involved.
It might be possible that only high school techniques are needed, but nothing comes to mind.)  My solution starts off focusing on these techniques, but I'm still unable to easily bridge the gap.

Solution: First, some definitions.
Let the teams be $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n$, collectively called $T$.
Let $2^T$ denote the power set of $T$, whose elements are subsets of $T$.
Let $f: 2^T \rightarrow 2^T$, where $f(S)$ is the set of teams that scored an odd number of points playing with all the teams in $S$, aka drew with an odd number of them.
We will make use of the symmetric difference operator $\triangle$ on sets. We will use it's properties (symmetric, commutative, identity is $\emptyset$, self-inverse, etc)  without proof.
Verify the following:

$f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$.
For any non-empty subset, $f(S) \neq \emptyset$ from the condition.
For any $t_i$, there exists $t_j \in f( t_i )$. Furthermore, $t_i \in f(t_j)$.
Corollary: The emptyset is the unique set that satisfies $f(S) = \emptyset$.
CRUX For subset $S$ and any team $t_i$, then $f(S \triangle t_i) = f(S) \triangle f(t_i)$ or equivalently that $f(S) \triangle f(S \triangle t_i)= f(t_i)$.

For $t_j \in f(t_i)$, the parity of matches it drew against $S$ and $S\triangle t_i$ is distinct, so it appears in $f(S) \triangle f(S \triangle t_i)$.
For $t_j \not \in f(t_j)$, the parity of matches it drew against $S$ and $S\triangle S_i$ is the same, so it doesn't appear in $f(S) \triangle f(S \triangle t_i)$.
Hence $f(t_i) = f(S) \triangle f(S \triangle t_i)$ as desired.


Corollary: $f(S) = \triangle_{t_i \in S} f(t_i)$.

Induct on $|S|$ using the previous observation.


Corollary: The set $ \{ f(t_i) \}$ is linearly independent under the symmetric operator.

$ \triangle_{t_i \in S} f(t_i) = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow f(S) = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow S = \emptyset $.


Consider the adjacency matrix, where $(i , j) = 1 $ iff $t_i \in f(f_j)$ iff $t_j \in f(t_i)$ iff $t_i, t_j$ drew.

Working in $\mathbb{F_2}$ (aka symmetric operator coefficient calculation), if $n$ is odd, we have a skew-symmetric matrix, hence it has determinant 0. (Standard linear algebra argument, EG See here.)
This contradicts the previous corollary that the range of the adjacency matrix (spanned by rows which are $f(t_i)$) has full dimension $n$.
Hence $n$ is not odd.




Notes

We do need the linear independence of all $ \{ f(t_i) \}$.

For example, it is not enough that there is some $S$ where $f(S) = T$.


Unlike what OP thinks, we do NOT need to show that "Prove that even $n$ could work".

However, if you follow the solution, all that we require is $ \{f(t_i) \}$  is linearly independent. This allows us to create several valid constructions, of which I'm listing 2 explicitly.

teams $ t_{2k-1}, t_{2k}$ drew,
every team drew with each other.




And if we decided to linear algebra our way directly, here is a short solution.

Consider the incidence matrix $A$ where $a_{ij} = 1$ iff teams $i, j$ had a draw. We work in $ \mathbb{F}_2$.
The question says that for any non-zero vector $s$ representing the non-empty subset $S$, then $As \neq 0$.
Observe that $A$ is skew symmetric.
Hence if $n$ is odd, then $\det A = 0$. Then, there exists a non-zero vector $s$ such that $As  = 0$. This is a contradiction.




Nice answer! I don’t fully follow what you are saying in the last bullet. Can you please explain?

@Pranay The last bullet about the construction for even $n$? If so I just made some edits to correct errors. $\quad$ I'm listing out 2 possible constructions. The first one is where team $t_{2k-1}, t_{2k+2}$ drew (IE We can form $n/2$ pairs that drew). The sets $f(t_i)$ is the other element of the pair, hence is linearly independent. $\quad$ The second construction is where everyone drew each other.  Then $f(t_i) = T - t_i$, hence is also linearly independent.

Yes, that’s what I was referring to. I see, it makes sense now. I thought you were constructing counterexample, not examples. In case it’s helpful, the complete graph on four vertices minus an edge is a possible graph of draws on four teams that doesn’t satisfy the given requirement even though there are even number of teams.

@Pranay Right, but that's not the problem asks. The problem didn't say that "For any football league on even $n$ teams, then for every subset $S$ of teams, there exists a team who scored an odd number of points against $S$". $\quad$ A more obvious counterexample is if there are no draws. Then $f(S) = \emptyset$ for all $S$.  $\quad$ Again, the important aspect here is that $f(S) = \triangle_{t_i \in S} f(t_i)$, and that the $ { f(t_i ) }$ has full rank.

Yes, I understand. Yeah that’s a much simpler example. I was trying to give a nonexample with even $n$ because the OP seemed to think one has to prove it’s possible for all even $n$. I understand that the original problem statement wasn’t “if and only if”.

Wow, I honestly didn't think I would come back here. I actually was able to come up with a construction that works for any even $n$ (a few days after the problem was posted), and I don't quite know how to disprove for odd $n$, but yeah, on second thought, I don't actually need to show that it works for any even $n$, but just that it doesn't work for odd $n$, something I didn't really consider.

Please see the other answer for the intended interpretation of the question
The wording “playing all the teams in $S$” suggests that the team must be outside $S$ because a team cannot play with itself. Then consider the graph whose vertices are the $n$ teams and there is edge between two vertices if there is a tie between the corresponding teams. Then every vertex has odd degree because for any $S$ such that $|S|=n-1$, the team outside $S$ has an odd number of ties with the teams in $S$. Therefore, by the handshake lemma, $n$ must be even.

See my comment earlier under the proposed question. I speculate that the interpretation you had might not be the intended interpretation.
